# Outlook 2010,2013 mystery table column widths

Tags: html, css, outlook, signature

I've got a email signature that renders alright in pretty much everything except Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013.

I've put all the content into a table but there's one column that is misbehaving so I've been experimenting around trying to find a fix. I've tried all the obvious things like removing padding and images but it still distorts the column width.

I've used litmus to simulate outlook 2013 and it produces this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfGYG.jpg - where instead there should be no gap at all

Here is the html/styling:

https://jsfiddle.net/LL9s1zds/1/

Can anyone work out why it's doing this? and what the fix is?

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.tg td{font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-name{font-size:16px;color:#333333;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;}
.tg .tg-titl{font-size:12px;vertical-align:top;padding-bottom:10px;}
.tg .tg-cont{vertical-align:middle;}
.tg .tg-con0{vertical-align:top;padding:3px;}
.tg .tg-con1{font-size:14px;vertical-align:middle;}
.tg .tg-con2{font-size:14px;vertical-align:middle;padding-bottom:20px;}
.tg .tg-conn{font-size:16px;letter-spacing:1px;}
.tg .tg-soci{vertical-align:middle;padding:15px 5px;}
.tg .tg-regu{font-size:10px;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-ban1{background-color:#E8001D;vertical-align:top;padding:12px;}
.tg .tg-ban2{background-color:#E8001D;vertical-align:top;padding:12px;padding-left:25px}
.tg .tg-ban3{background-color:#E8001D;vertical-align:top;padding:12px;padding-left:40px}
.tg .tg-etce{font-size:10px;color:#009900;vertical-align:middle}
.tg .tg-envi{font-size:10px;color:#009900;padding-top:10px;}
.tg .tg-reg1{vertical-align:middle;padding-left:50px;padding-top:10px;}
.tg .tg-reg2{vertical-align:middle;padding-left:20px;padding-top:15px;}
.tg .tg-reg3{vertical-align:middle;padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px;}
</style>
<br>
<table class="tg" style="und;table-layout:fixed;width:600px;">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 21px">
<col style="width: 166px">
<col style="width: 58px">
<col style="width: 58px">
<col style="width: 58px">
<col style="width: 58px">
<col style="width: 58">
<col style="width: 58">
<col style="width: 58">
</colgroup>
<tr>
<th class="tg-name" colspan="9">%%displayname%%</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-titl" colspan="9">%%title%%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-cont"><img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/phone.png" alt="phone"></td>
<td class="tg-con1" colspan="8">%%phonenumber%%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-cont"><img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/mail.png" alt="e-mail"></td>
<td class="tg-con1" colspan="8">%%email%%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-con0"><img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/pin.png" alt="address"></td>
<td class="tg-con2" colspan="8">%%street%%, %%city%%, %%zipcode%%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-ban1" colspan="2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/158/32/" alt="Company Logo"></td>
<td class="tg-ban2" colspan="3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/31/" alt="Award 1"></td>
<td class="tg-ban3" colspan="4"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/177/31/" alt="award2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-conn" colspan="2">Connect With Us</td>
<td class="tg-soci">
    <a href=http://twitter.com/>
        <img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/tw.png" alt="Twitter"></a></td>
<td class="tg-soci">
    <a href=http://facebook.com/>
        <img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a></td>
<td class="tg-soci">
    <a href=http://plus.google.com/>
        <img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/gp.png" alt="Google Plus"></a></td>
<td class="tg-soci">
    <a href=http://youtube.com/user/>
        <img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/yt.png" alt="YouTube"></a></td>
<td class="tg-soci">
    <a href=http://instagram.com/>
        <img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/ig.png" alt="Instagram"></a></td>
<td class="tg-soci">
    <a href=http://pinterest.com/>
        <img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/pi.png" alt="Pintrest"></a></td>
<td class="tg-soci">
    <a href=http://blog..co.uk/feed/>
        <img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/rs.png" alt="Blog RSS"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-regu" colspan="9">This message and any attachments are intended for the individual to whom they are specifically addressed to above. Any views expressed in this email are those of the individual sender, except where specifically stated otherwise. Registered Office: 123 Fake Street, Glasgow</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-etce"><img src="http://serviceteamit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/environment.png" alt="think before printing"></td>
<td class="tg-envi" colspan="3">Please consider the environment before printing this email</td>
<td class="tg-reg1" colspan="2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/58/39/" alt="3"></td>
<td class="tg-reg2" colspan="2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/78/37/" alt="3"></td>
<td class="tg-reg3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/35/35/" alt="3"></td>
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to remove the colspans from your table. Outlook tends to freak out when using colspan and rowspan. Rather nest your table as shown here:

https://www.lehigh.edu/~inwww/seminar/intermediate/tables/table-nest.html

Comment: Cheers pal, that took a while to re-do but it seems to have worked in litmus. Awaiting further testing, but I'm tentatively going to say that worked.

Comment: fantastic! Glad to be of help!

Comment: I've added it as an answer - when you have moment, please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to remove the colspans from your table.

Outlook tends to freak out when using colspan and rowspan.

Rather nest your table as shown here: http://lehigh.edu/~inwww/seminar/intermediate/tables/table-nest.html